# conforming to a protocol require delegate variable be available in ios13

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, urlsession, urlsessionwebsockettask

having this protocol

```
 public protocol URLSessionWebSocketTaskProtocol {

    func send(_ message: URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
    func receive(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message, Error>) -> Void)
    func sendPing(pongReceiveHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
    func cancel(with closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?)
    func resume()
}
```

and conforming to it in this part

```
extension URLSessionWebSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTaskProtocol {}
```

works fine, but I need to have delegate property in the protocol so modified the protocol to this

```
public protocol URLSessionWebSocketTaskProtocol {

func send(_ message: URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
func receive(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message, Error>) -> Void)
func sendPing(pongReceiveHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
func cancel(with closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?)
func resume()
var delegate: URLSessionTaskDelegate? { get set}
```

}

now the compiler tells that

> Protocol 'URLSessionWebSocketTaskProtocol' requires 'delegate' to be available in iOS 13.0.0 and newer

the target minimun version is set to iOS 13, so it should be necessary to add the @available(iOS 13.0, *), but added any way and there is not change the compilers keeps telling that protocol requires delegate to be available in iOS 13.
**URLWebSocketTask** does not have a delegate property per se it inherits from **URLSessionTask** that have a delegate Property of type **URLSessionTaskDelegate** and URLWebSocketTaskDelegate comforms to URlSessionTaskDelegate.

so how I could add a delegate to the protocol and the conformance does not show that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `URLSessionWebSocketTask` is-a `NSURLSessionTask`, which has `delegate` only (!!) since iOS 15:

```
@interface NSURLSessionTask : NSObject <NSCopying, NSProgressReporting>

@property (nullable, retain) id <NSURLSessionTaskDelegate> delegate 
API_AVAILABLE(macos(12.0), ios(15.0), watchos(8.0), tvos(15.0));
```

so if you want to fit that API contract, you need to do same in your protocol, like:

```
public protocol URLSessionWebSocketTaskProtocol {

    // ... other methods here

    @available(iOS 15, *)                               // << here !!
    var delegate: URLSessionTaskDelegate? { get set }

}
```

of course alternate is to make extension limited to iOS15+, like

```
@available(iOS 15, *)
extension URLSessionWebSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTaskProtocol {
}
```

Verified with Xcode 13.2.1